# DataTable as Declarative Data Source?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, telerik

I am using a Telerik's Grid that unveils its potential if it's bout to a declarative data source. However I do not have a need to create a database table but just would like to use standard `DataTable` as my data storage.

The component item I want to  use does require `DataSource` for binding.  (`GridDropDownColumn` in Telerik RadGrid).

Is there a way to make a Data Source (suitable for decralative binding to components) that uses a simple `DataTable` as storage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is.

Simply use an `ObjectDataSource`.  In its selectMethod, point it to a method in your codebehind (or any where else) that returns your `DataTable`.

Comment: awesome, thanks! Telerik's docs are too many of letters to get the idea. :)

Comment: Is there a super-simple example of _how_ to do this anywhere? It seems like a heavyweight solution for what ought to be nothing.